# How to save the state of css background-color property change when navigating away from one menu to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For eg.  I have the following nav menu.[image]

And here's my jquery code that looks at click events on the nav menus.

```
//background colors setup for each nav menu
var colors_array_by_class = {"home" : "#111111", "about-us" : "#47F514", "campaigns" : "#F2720A", "news" : "#0A76F2", "donate" : "#F7A116" };

$("ul.nav").on('click', 'li > a', function(){
            $("ul.nav > li > a").css("background-color", "#0E0E0E");
            $(this).css("background-color", colors_array_by_class[$(this).children("i").attr('class')]);
});
```

When user clicks on the News menu, the News menu's css background-color will change to blue, which is what it's expected of the code above does.  But as the user is navigating to the news page, the page refreshes, then the News menu's css background-color reverted back to the original color.

This is not the correct behaviour I want.  I want the changed background-color to be saved as the user navigates away in another page thus I'm trying to figure out what are the available approaches can I do to achieve this?  I was thinking of adding extra array parameter to the colors_arrays_by_class array where I give each menu class its own default state values and they get changed each time user navigates around the pages.

But I'm just not sure if this approach is correct to take...

What do you think?

Comment: You can try using local storage feature of HTML5. I think it is best suitable for your requirement. get help from here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Yes.  I was thinking about using that option too.  But is that really necessary for the simple menu tabs like this?  I would have though HTML5 feature is only more beneficial if you're storing user's data objects when navigating the sites such as a typical ecommerce sites....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## With CSS (preferred)

Add a class or property to the body that identifies the page. HTML5's `data-*` properties are just the thing for this. If you are using PHP, it might look like this:

```
<body data-page-name="<?= $pageName; ?>">
```

Then, in your CSS, you have some of the following CSS rules:

```
body[data-page-name="home"] ul.nav { background-color: #111 }
body[data-page-name="about-us"] ul.nav { background-color: #47F514; }
body[data-page-name="campaigns"] ul.nav { background-color: #F2720A; }
body[data-page-name="news"] ul.nav { background-color: #0A76F2; }
body[data-page-name="donate"] ul.nav { background-color: #F7A116; }
```

## With Javascript (fun)

You want to pass info along to the next page, and then, when loading the page, retrieve that info. You can pass info between pages three ways: localStorage and cookies.

### Cookies

Firstly, download [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). It is a jQuery plugin to simplify your life when you want to use cookies.

This is how a setter looks: (assigning a value to a new variable)

```
$.cookie('key','value');
```

This is how a getter looks: (retrieving the value of a variable)

```
$.cookie('key');
```

### localStorage

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) is a new feature in HTML5 as an alternative to cookies. You have basic key-value pairs, similar to Redis.

Setters look like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('key','value');
```

And getters look like this:

```
localStorage.getItem('key'); // returns "value"
```

*Just so you know, you can also use sessionStorage. Usage is the same, but the client doesn't retain the data on the next visit*

### Tying it together

Now, sessionStorage/localStorage would be the preferred approach if the client's browser supports it. So you should do a check before caching and info to know what to do. Bringing it all together, your code might look something like this:

```
$(function () {

    // Check for background color
    if ( typeof sessionStorage !== "undefined" ) {
        var menuBackgroundColor = sessionStorage.getItem('menuBackgroundColor');
        sessionStorage.removeItem('menuBackgroundColor');
    } else {
        var menuBackgroundColor = $.cookie('menuBackgroundColor');
        $.removeCookie('menuBackgroundColor')
    }

    //background colors setup for each nav menu
    var colors_array_by_class = {
        "home"      : "#111111",
        "about-us"  : "#47F514",
        "campaigns" : "#F2720A",
        "news"      : "#0A76F2",
        "donate"    : "#F7A116"
    };

    // Click event
    $("ul.nav").on('click', 'li > a', function(){

        // Cache new menu color for later use
        var newMenuColor = colors_array_by_class[ $(this).children("i").attr('class') ];

        // Visual change
        $("ul.nav > li > a").css("background-color", "#0E0E0E");
        $(this).css("background-color", newMenuColor );

        if ( typeof sessionStorage !== "undefined" )
            localStorage.setItem('menuBackgroundColor', newMenuColor );
        else
            $.cookie('menuBackgroundColor', newMenuColor );

    });
})();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  This definitely very useful.. Although I couldn't get the part where you retrieve localstorage's newMenuBackgroundColor value onto a php value so I use it to set the data value on the body tags.  May I ask how to pass the value from Javascript to Php environment?

Comment: Using `$.cookie('name','value')` will save a cookie called `name`, whose value is `value`. You can retrieve the value from PHP using `$_COOKIE['name']`.

Comment: As for localStorage, for this feature exactly, you won't need to retrieve it in PHP. The client (the browser) will remember the variable, but NOT the server (PHP). This means you cannot retrieve the localStorage value.

Answer (score 0):

It's customary, in cases like this, to have a 'selected-tab' class that gives the given tab a particular style(say, a, blue background).

You'll just have to add such a class and attach it to the News tab in the News page

Comment: Okay.  This can work.  It's similar to what I was originally thinking in the above with the extra parameter in the array.  I'll give this one a go.  Thanks.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is it only highlights the `li` in the menu. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, the entire menu should change color.